# Find all <img> tags and replace them by their src (NODEJS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex

(EDIT) This should be implemented in a nodeJS back end application so trying to avoid DOMParser()

I have a string of a mix of text and  tags like so:

```
This is a comment

<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129324867-83b2e2bf-52c7-4dc6-a8b6-760194e2a875.png">

Some more comment

<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129335514-e7e921e9-eb1e-4848-b197-a2438bcc7bd3.png">

This is the end of the comment
```

I would like to create a function that replaces the <img > tags by what is inside the src tag like so:

```
This is a comment

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129324867-83b2e2bf-52c7-4dc6-a8b6-760194e2a875.png

Some more comment

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129335514-e7e921e9-eb1e-4848-b197-a2438bcc7bd3.png

This is the end of the comment
```

I've played around with Regex but couldn't find a way to make it work. Any suggestions welcome !

Comment: What are you trying to do with the src URL?

Comment: I'm sending it to a slack conversations so Slack displays a thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This snippet does the job:

```js
const contents = `This is a comment

<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129324867-83b2e2bf-52c7-4dc6-a8b6-760194e2a875.png">

Some more comment

<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129335514-e7e921e9-eb1e-4848-b197-a2438bcc7bd3.png">

This is the end of the comment`;

const re = /(<img.+src=")(.*)(">)/ig;
const parsedContents = contents.replace(re, "$2");
console.log(parsedContents);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This should work but I haven't tested it:

This uses the [DOMParser Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString).

```
const doc = domparser.parseFromString(string, "text/html");

Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll("img")).forEach((img) => {
  img.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(img.src), img);
});

console.log(doc.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I found this work.
You can find more about DOMParser [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var htmlString = `This is a comment

<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129324867-83b2e2bf-52c7-4dc6-a8b6-760194e2a875.png">

Some more comment

<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129335514-e7e921e9-eb1e-4848-b197-a2438bcc7bd3.png">

This is the end of the comment`

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

var allImg = doc.body.querySelectorAll('img')
allImg.forEach(function(item){
    var src = item.getAttribute('src') || ''
    item.replaceWith(src)
})

console.log(htmlString, '\n-------\n' ,doc.body.innerText)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work in a browser, I might need to use an external library like jsondom to make it work in NODEJS

Comment: @SydneyC. oops, I didn't know it's suppose to work on NodeJs. I will dig a little more

Comment: it wasn't clear in my original message. Someone found a great work around I accepted it as a good answer thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Look for all the elements in the page.

`var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");`

Step 2 : `var x` is the array of all images in the document. Using loop, get all values using

`x[i].src`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = `This is a comment
<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129324867-83b2e2bf-52c7-4dc6-a8b6-760194e2a875.png"/>
Some more comment
<img width="232" alt="CleanShot 2021-08-13 at 10 03 02@2x" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10532381/129335514-e7e921e9-eb1e-4848-b197-a2438bcc7bd3.png"/>
This is the end of the comment`;

let imgs = input.match(/<.+>/g);
let srcs = imgs.map(img => img.match(/src=".+"/g)[0])
            .map(src => src.substring(0, src.length-1).replace('src="', ''));

for(let i=0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    input = input.replace(imgs[i], srcs[i]);
}

console.log(input);
```